# Create vector of trait objects

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I am trying to create a vector of trait objects but I'm getting a type mismatch. I also tried using `.map()` instead of a for loop but had the same problem. This is a minimal version of my real code, I realise this example doesn't require the use of trait objects but my real code does since there will be types other than `Link` in the List, which also implement `Speak`. How can I create a `Vec` with the correct type so I can pass it to `trait_objects`?

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    // let links = fs::read_dir("my_dir").unwrap();
    // let links: Vec<Box<dyn Speak>> = links
    //     .map(|file| {
    //         let myfile = file.unwrap();
    //         let href = myfile.path().to_str().unwrap();
    //         Box::new(Link { attr: href })
    //     })
    //     .collect();

    let links = Vec::new();
    for entry in fs::read_dir("my_dir").unwrap() {
        let myfile = entry.unwrap();
        let href = myfile.path().to_str().unwrap();
        links.push(Box::new(Link { attr: href }));
    }

    let link_objects = ListOfTraitObjects {
        trait_objects: links,
    };
    for link in link_objects.trait_objects.iter() {
        println!("{}", link.speak());
    }
}
trait Speak {
    fn speak(&self) -> String;
}

struct ListOfTraitObjects {
    trait_objects: Vec<Box<dyn Speak>>,
}

struct Link<'a> {
    attr: &'a str,
}
impl Speak for Link<'_> {
    fn speak(&self) -> String {
        self.attr.to_string()
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=866d8162a5e1f250c52abe37271bb306)?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code. The first is that you're creating a `Vec<Box<Link>>` instead of a `Vec<Box<Speak>>`. By default `Box::new (foo)` creates a box of the same type as `foo`. If you want a box of some trait implemented by `foo`, you need to be explicit:

```
links.push(Box::new(Link { attr: href }) as Box::<dyn Speak>);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b5f0b6ad5ecc14ad512023a8fa68b740)

However this gives two new errors:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/lib.rs:7:20
  |
7 |         let href = myfile.path().to_str().unwrap();
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                    |
  |                    creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
8 |         links.push(Box::new(Link { attr: href }) as Box::<dyn Speak>);
  |                    ----------------------------- cast requires that borrow lasts for `'static`

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `links` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:8:9
  |
4 |     let links = Vec::new();
  |         ----- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut links`
...
8 |         links.push(Box::new(Link { attr: href }) as Box::<dyn Speak>);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

The first error is because your `Link` struct *borrows* a string from `entry`, but `entry` only lives as long as the current loop iteration. Even though the error states that the *cast* requires a `'static` lifetime, you would get a similar error if you were simply trying to build a `Vec<Link>` without casting ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=194e0dc66f57b386155ba9e46696f60a)). You need to change the definition of your `Link` struct to contain an owned string:

```
struct Link {
    attr: String,
}
impl Speak for Link {
    fn speak(&self) -> String {
        self.attr.clone()
    }
}
```

The second error is easier and can be fixed simply by following the compiler suggestion and replacing `let links = …` with `let mut links = …`.

Full working example:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let mut links = Vec::new();
    for entry in fs::read_dir("my_dir").unwrap() {
        let myfile = entry.unwrap();
        let href = myfile.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string();
        links.push(Box::new(Link { attr: href }) as Box::<dyn Speak>);
    }

    let link_objects = ListOfTraitObjects {
        trait_objects: links,
    };
    for link in link_objects.trait_objects.iter() {
        println!("{}", link.speak());
    }
}
trait Speak {
    fn speak(&self) -> String;
}

struct ListOfTraitObjects {
    trait_objects: Vec<Box<dyn Speak>>,
}

struct Link {
    attr: String,
}
impl Speak for Link {
    fn speak(&self) -> String {
        self.attr.clone()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=866d8162a5e1f250c52abe37271bb306)

The same fixes can be applied to your iterator-based solution:

```
let links = fs::read_dir("my_dir").unwrap();
let links: Vec<_> = links
    .map(|file| {
        let myfile = file.unwrap();
        let href = myfile.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string();
        Box::new(Link { attr: href }) as Box<dyn Speak>
    })
    .collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35786dd3d6534daa67208f21b815019e)